# TS1146: Declaration expected .. why?

Tags: angular, components, angular-components

I'm with a small problem.

I probably because I'm tired, sorry, I could not found the solution. 
Somebody can help me?

I have this file: **src/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgClass } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ServerComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Than inside of this component I create a new component, as sample of course.

**src/app/server/server.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-server',
 templateUrl: ''
});
export class ServerComponent {
};
```

**src/app/server/serve.component.html**

```
<p>
 Start simple
</p>
```

Super simple, right? I agree.
But when I try to run, I get this error:

> 70% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active ERROR in
>   src/app/server/server.component.ts(6,3): error TS1146: Declaration
>   expected.

The system can not find the file **(server.component.ts)**, but I did put the path correctly here (**src/app/app.module.ts**), I did declaration, I did **import { Component } from '@angular/core';**
, so .. what is missing? I cant understand.

Thanks all.

Comment: Don't add 'Solved' to the title. The proper way to mark a question as solved is to provide an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

you shouldn't put semicolon before export

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-server',
 templateUrl: ''
 })
 export class ServerComponent {
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes extra curly brackets throw such error.
**angular**